# Server Requests to unknown pages

Tags: mysql, system-administration

I'm trying to manage my blog but the MySQL database keeps overloading and knocking the server offline. When i look through the requests to the server, i see a lot of requests such as:

```
GET /?pagerd_ttfrh HTTP/1.1
```

I'm a web developer at heart, so my sysadmin abilities are very limited, does anyone know what this request is, and whether it should be 90% of the requests to the server? I felt that it may be related to a bad advert spamming the server but i can't really put my finger on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The request that is shown just shows a request to your homepage (/index) using the get parameter "pagerd_ttfrh", this could be a valid url.
But as a web developer you probably know that already.

There are 3 things I would check ASAP:

1.) A link to your site with the given url is posted on the internet somewhere and generating a lot of requests, or somehow some searchbots hitting this url more that needed. Check your logfiles to see or those request originate from the same source(s) and check what those source(s) are.

2.) The sql you use on your website is badly optimised and is breaking your site. Set a slow-log for instance, maybe even count your queries or use a debugger to detect sql issues caused by ORM or other abstraction layers.

3.) The (shared) server is to small to handle your load.
Check your system resources, check your server load ect ect.